# Drag and Drop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to add to my site drag and drop when I upload video. But when I upload, "Browse" don't change and I don't see the image of the video. Where is the problem?

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="waretoken">
  <p><label for="id_department">Department:</label>
    <select name="departmet" required="" id="id_department">
      <option value="" selected="">-----</option>
      <option value="2">opt1</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <div onload="DAD()">
  <script src="drag_to_drop.js"></script>
```

```js
function handleDrop(e){
  var dt= e.dataTransfer;
  var file= dt.files;
  if(file[0]['type'] == 'video/mp4'){
    file_input.files = file;
    file_input.select(file);
    console.log(file_input.files);
    dropArea.classList.add('success');
  } else{
    dropArea.classList.remove('success');
    dropArea.classList.add('error');
  }  
}
```

Comment: `<script sr="drag_to_drop.js">` I've no idea what's in the script file you're trying to load - but this won't load it because the attribute is `src`, not `sr`